# Should I use terraform termplate or devops pipeline to upload docker images in multiple region in public cloud?

Tags: terraform, chef-infra, devops

This may sound naive, I have to upload docker images in all subscribed regions in public cloud. And I am planning to do it in terraform template and will create a `null_resource` with multiple `local-exec` provisioner to login into docker repo, docker tag and docker push.

In future, we can subscribe to more cloud regions so number of regions might change in future.

I am not sure terraform is a better choice or I should think about some devops pipeline. I have basic understanding of terraform and have no idea how devops pipeline works?

Any suggestion?

Comment: People generally do this with a pipeline as it naturally fits into the final stage after build, test, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both, so I have Terraform to make all my resources and then I use an Azure Dev Ops pipeline to make the magic happen.

Here is my pipeline code, that I used to spin up terraform:

```html
parameters:
  - name: terraformWorkingDirectory
    type: string
    default: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform
  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string
    default: VALUE
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
    default: VALUE
  - name: appconnectionname
    type: string
    default: VALUE
  - name: backendresourcegroupname   
    type: string
    default: Terraform
  - name: backendstorageaccountname
    type: string
    default: terraform
  - name: backendcontainername
    type: string
    default: terraformstatefile
  - name: RG
    type: string
    default: rg_example
  - name: azureLocation
    type: string
    default: UK South
  - name: terraformVersion
    type: string
    default: 1.0.4
  - name: artifactName
    type: string
    default: Website

jobs:
  - job: Run_Terraform
    displayName: Installing and Running Terraform
    steps:
      - checkout: Terraform
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: install
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: '${{ parameters.terraformVersion }}'
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' 
            dir
      - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: init
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: init
          backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.backendresourcegroupname }}'
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '${{ parameters.backendstorageaccountname }}'
          backendAzureRmContainerName: '${{ parameters.backendcontainername }}'
          backendAzureRmKey: terraform.tfstate
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: plan
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: plan
          commandOptions: '-input=false'
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'
      - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
        displayName: apply
        inputs:
          provider: azurerm
          command: apply
          commandOptions: '-input=false -auto-approve'
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.terraformWorkingDirectory }}'

  - job: Put_artifacts_into_place
    displayName: Putting_artifacts_into_place
    dependsOn: Run_Terraform
    steps:
      - checkout: Website
      - checkout: AuthenticationServer

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download Build Artifacts
        inputs:
          artifact: '${{ parameters.artifactName }}'
          patterns: /**/*.zip
          path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: VALUE'
        inputs:
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)**/*.zip
          azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
          ConnectedServiceName: '${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}'
          appName: VALUE
          ResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.RG}}'

      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download Build Artifacts
        inputs:
          artifact: '${{ parameters.artifactName}}'
          patterns: /authsrv/**/*.zip
          path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/authsrv/
          
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: VALUE'
        inputs:
          package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/authsrv/**/*.zip
          azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}'
          ConnectedServiceName: '${{ parameters.appconnectionname}}'
          appName: VALUE
          ResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.RG}}'
```

What you would have to do is make a repo in Git or Azure it's a bit easier in Azure as you won't have to make a service connection to git, so there is less to go wrong...

Once you have a repo you then have to set up a remote backend, I did this using these azure commands:

```html
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "myTerraformbackend" -Location "UK South"
New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myTerraformbackend" -AccountName "myterraformstate" -Location UK South -SkuName Standard_LRS
New-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName "myTerraformbackend" -AccountName "nsdevopsterraform" -ContainerName "terraformstatefile"
```

I also followed this great blog post by Julie Ng, she works for Microsoft and she talks about the best practices for remote state files: https://julie.io/writing/terraform-on-azure-pipelines-best-practices/ she also has a youtube channel massive help.

In my terraform code I also use a bunch of local variables they are handy but make sure you have something created that is original that you can refer to mine is the resource group id. It's the first thing that's set up and then all my resources refer to that id.

Here look:

```html
locals {
  # Ids for Resource Group, merged together with unique string
  resource_group_id_full_value = format("${azurerm_resource_group.terraform.id}")
  resource_group_id            = substr(("${azurerm_resource_group.terraform.id}"), 15, 36)

  resource_group_id_for_login = substr(("${azurerm_resource_group.terraform.id}"), 15, 8)
  sql_admin_login             = format("${random_string.sql_name_random.id}-${local.resource_group_id_for_login}")

  sql_server_name = format("sqlserver-${local.resource_group_id}")

  sql_server_database_name = format("managerserver-${local.resource_group_id}")
}
```

You will understand this more really as you go.

I keep clear of `null_resource` I've seen a lot of people on here have problems with them, I use them sparingly.

If you're going to use Terraform for docker consider terraforms new feature, Terraform waypoint: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-waypoint

You also have Terraform workspaces to handle remote states now but I haven't had time to look into this.

I hope this information is helpful and a good starting reference.